# Make a unique together constraint on django that is not historically recognized

Tags: mysql, django, postgresql

Suppose I have a table where I just added a new field.  I (and by that I mean a co-worker) applied a data migration that did not satisfy a unique_together constraint that we have yet to put in.  So the migration succeeded.

However now we want to add in a unique_together constraint, what is the proper process?  I can think of three possibilities, none of which seem super attractive

1. Do I have to go back through and force the unique together constraint manually, then do the migration to alter the field?
2. Change the field and it will only apply to newer entries (SQL ignores the old entries that violate the constraint...pretty sure this isn't a thing)
3. Undo the data migration, migrate to the unique_together, then do a valid data migration (this seems like the "right" thing do but it will be difficult in practice)

It should be noted that the old rows that do violate the unique_together constraint I really don't care about anymore.

I'm on django 1.7 and using postgresql

Comment: You're right that 2) isn't possible, so you have to ensure the validity of the data before you apply the constraint. How you get the data in a valid state is really up to you, whichever seems easiest to do considering the current state of the data and data migrations.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Do I have to go back through and force the unique together constraint manually, then do the migration to alter the field?

I wouldn't recommend this, because you'll end up with a set of migrations that could break on other deployments. You might be able to get away with it if you have just the one database, but in that case I would reset your migrations after the fact. What you don't want is to be left with a set of migrations that will fail when they are re-run.

> 2. Change the field and it will only apply to newer entries (SQL ignores the old entries that violate the constraint...pretty sure this isn't a thing)

This does seem to be possible on at least some databases. I'm not sure what all the practical consequences of this are, but it seems like a bad idea. You mentioned that you don't really care about these rows. If you don't care so much that you can actually delete them, then problem solved! But if you care enough to keep them around, you should ensure that they are consistent with your database schema (including the constraints).

> 3. Undo the data migration, migrate to the unique_together, then do a valid data migration (this seems like the "right" thing do but it will be difficult in practice)

This does indeed seem like the right thing to do, and I can't think of a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

There is the django way:

4. You write a custom migration that takes care about the data in the table before the other migration runs, that creates the db-constraint.